# deleted objects still in scene

Tags: materials, objects, linked-data, scene

I have a couple of objects in scene that were deleted and they still show up in blender file and data blocks view and their materials aswell and I cannot select them and I cannot unlink them and make local does nothing...

How I remove these unused objects and their materials?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might find it valuable to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and review the sections of the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help), especially those parts about asking and answering questions. For myself, I can't be of much help because I can't see your file from where I am. You might want to upload some screenshots, and upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit the4 screenshots and a link to the blend file into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit sparse on information so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

In your outliner panel where it says All Scenes, select Orphan Data, if the data which should be gone is visible there you can press Purge All to remove the data from the scene.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

With that little information I can only guess. The problem is most likely one of these:

1. You deleted a mesh in Edit mode. If that's the case you only deleted the vertex data of your object but not the object with all its information itself. Check your Outliner Window for leftovers. Right-click on the one you want to delete and choose "Delete" from the menu.
   [image]
2. You imported the objects from obj and for a strange reason there are still leftovers after deleting them again. Again, check your Outliner Window for leftovers.
3. You had double objects in the scene (but maybe not on the same layer). Check your Outliner Window, if there are still copies around.
4. You created these objects by copying/separating them from a bigger mesh and that bigger mesh still contains the originals. In that case, in Edit Mode, do not copy meshes and separate them, just separate them without copying  or delete the unwanted vertices.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of deleted text re-appearing in renders, in my case I did the following.

1. Ensure every object you want to keep in your file appears in the graphics editing window.
2. put cursor in graphic editing window and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> once.
3. Select everything that is visible by typing the letter <kbd>A</kbd> (or use menus)
4. Copy everything that is visible by typing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or use menus)
5. Open a new file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (or use menus)
6. In the graphics editing window of your new untitled file <kbd>Left Click</kbd> click once.
7. Paste everything you selected in step 3) by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (or menus)
8. Use *Save As* to save your newly made untitled file to work on in future.